# Limit cursor movement in UITextView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview

I have a custom (subclassed) `UITextView` where all properties of a standard `UITextView` are inherited.

The user is able to write, delete, cut, copy, paste, etc. What i would like to do is limit the cursor movement to a specific location in the text-view, such that, the user may change the cursor position (`textView.selectedRange.location`) upto a certain point only, as the text beyond that point is supposed to be non-user-editable. I have successfully handled this on single tap event by overriding the `textViewDidChangeSelection` method. But the cursor still moves to the text beyond the desired point on long press (when the magnifier appears).

Is there a way to limit cursor movement after the magnifier appears, to keep it in the desired sub-range?

Comment: You have to dig into the [`UITextInput Protocol`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/UITextInput/selectedTextRange)

Comment: You were right. `UITextInput` Protocol is.....magical.

Comment: :) I'm glad you took my comment in action and you are no more n00b programmer now.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved it.

```
- (CGRect) caretRectForPosition:(UITextPosition *)position{

if (self.selectedRange.location > desiredLength)
    self.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(desiredLength, self.selectedRange.length);

return [super caretRectForPosition:position];
}
```

Used this function as it's called every time the cursor is moved, irrespective of what else is happening in the `UITextView`